# Handle login with user and password using selenium and VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, popup

i have a trouble to authenticate my credentials using selenium with a chrome driver and VBA.

I need to download a file from a webpage which need that user put its credentials.

I read something in some forums and i could got this code:

```
    Sub test()
    
    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    ch.AddArgument "start-maximized" ' Maximizar la pantalla del navegador
    ch.Get ("http://gremio:@Dialer2022@https://www.dialer.com.ar/lista/archivos
/Lista_Gremio_Dialer.xlsx")
    
       
    End Sub
```

When I run the code, I get a web page access error:

https://i.postimg.cc/wT0nTyk4/AAA.png

https://i.postimg.cc/T3cjXgqh/dd.png

If i put only the webpage : https://www.dialer.com.ar/lista/archivos/Lista_Gremio_Dialer.xlsx

i can get in on the webpage and then i have to put my credentials:
https://i.postimg.cc/2S19kHy3/bb.png

and the the user and password:
https://i.postimg.cc/hG9rvNB4/cc.png

But i need automatize the download routine with selenium and VBA.

For example if i try with another page with the same code, works fine.

```
    Sub test()
    
    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    ch.AddArgument "start-maximized" ' Maximizar la pantalla del navegador
    ch.Get ("http://test:test@browserspy.dk/password-ok.php")

    End Sub
```

I think that the problem is about pop up on the page.

I really appreciated some kind of help, thank you very much.

Comment: Why put 'http://gremio:@Dialer2022' at the beginning?  which could put the credentials automatically?

Comment: Hi navylover, the code i've got is as I put it in the post . How suppose could i put the credentials automatically? Thanks.